# Why do you need to specify type of extern/ static variable at initialization?

Tags: c++, static, extern

I do not understand the need to specify the type of an extern/static variable at initialization. For example:

```
struct Test{
 static int i;
};
 Test::i = 2; //error
 int Test::i = 2; //ok
```

Doesn't the compiler know that i is of type int? Is it just a particularity of the compilers, or why is specification of the type,,int" needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I do not understand the need to specify the type of an extern/static variable at initialization.

Because the language designers chose to use the same syntax for variable declarations and definitions. That syntax includes the type name. You're correct that, in some cases, that type name is redundant. But allowing you to leave it out might be somewhat confusing: it would look like an assignment, not a definition.

> Doesn't the compiler know that i is of type int?

Only if the variable has already been declared. That has to be the case for a static member like this, but not necessarily for a global variable. You could declare it in one source file:

```
extern int i;
```

and define it in another

```
int i = 42;
```

without making the declaration available to the definition.

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of basic syntax.

A C++ file consists of a series of declarations. The basic syntax for a variable declaration is something like:

> `type` `identifier` `initializer`<sub>opt</sub> ;

I'm leaving out a lot of details, but that's the basic idea: what's at file scope has to be a declaration, and a variable declaration has to start with the name of a type.

Without the name of a type on the beginning, you have a simple assignment statement--but those are only allowed inside of functions, not at file scope as you've tried to do it here.

Answer (score 1):

This "limitation" can be reduced to simple grammar: The statement

```
Test::i = 2; //error
```

is an expression-statement consisting of an assignment-expression. This is never actually parsed as a declaration, whatever the entity `Test::i` may be, and adjusting the grammar to cover this would be extremely complicated and have no great benefit whatsoever.

Comment: This answer would be massively stronger if you could cite an ambiguity it would cause (that's can't be trivially disambiguated by observing whether it appears inside or outside a function).

Comment: @TonyD Can't think of any simple and convincing example right now, so I'll take that out of the answer for now.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of valid, runnable code that would become ambiguous if the type weren't specified in the definition of the integer `N::X::i`, given the use of the disambiguating `struct` is possible for structures but there's nothing equivalent to force the `int  X::i` definition not to match the `struct` under your proposed syntax.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace N
{
  struct X
  {
    static int i;
    struct i { int n_; };
  };
}

int n = 2;

namespace N
{
  int X::i (n);   // take int out and under current C++ rules
                  // it will be equivalent to the next line
                  // (which is equivalent to struct X::i n; btw)
  struct X::i (n); // but under your proposed rules, ambiguous
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << N::n.n_ << ' ' << N::X::i << '\n';
}
```

That's a bit convoluted, but the bottom line is: not having types mentioned could break stuff.

Other answers basically amount to consistency with variable definitions appearing in other situations - that's desirable but not a sound technical driver to decide against the simplification proposed in the question.  Of course, it may not be enough of a simplification, or may be seen as more of an obfuscation, preventing it ever having been seriously considered for Standardisation.

Comment: What exactly could `X::i{n}` be interpreted as, if not the definition of the integer?

Comment: @Columbo; a definition of a global variable of type (`struct`) `X::i` named `n`.  (The superfluous parentheses are accepted, famously leading to the most vexing parse issue).

Comment: ... but you use curled braces there, so the rule in §8.3/6 does not apply. Did you mean `X::i(n)`?

Comment: @Columbo: oh yes - typing on my TV (HTPC setup) using a damned Japanese keyboard and the font's too small to see the difference - thanks for that.  Cheers.

Comment: @Columbo: and sorry - my first comment/reply shouldn't have said global - it's in namespace N of course....